# Where to see Azure HDInsight script actions error log

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

Getting the below error Message in Azure UI.

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"CustomizationFailedErrorCode\",\r\n \"message\": \"Cluster deployment failed due to an error in the custom script action. Failed Actions: 'createLivyFolder',Please go to Ambari UI to further debug the failure.\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, Got the log location.
The storage logs are available at 
\STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME\DEFAULT_CONTAINER_NAME\custom-scriptaction-logs\CLUSTER_NAME\DATE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux